# convert from typescript to traditional node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am having a newbie question and I have tried to read the manuals over and over and cannot figure it out.

so I have this code:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const serviceAccount = require('../service-account.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

import { ApolloServer, ApolloError, ValidationError, gql } from 'apollo-server';

interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  screenName: string;
  statusesCount: number;
}
```

Where I want to convert it to nodeJs (using normal javascript). I already managed this:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { ApolloServer, ApolloError, ValidationError, gql } = require('apollo-server');

}


const serviceAccount = require('../service-account.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

}
```

However I really do not know how to convert that interface to javascript/nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no way.
Just remove interface definition.

However you may want to have some kind of hint what exactly are in `User`, in that case you could create jsdoc definition.

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} User
 * @property {string} id
 * @property {string} name
 * @property {string} screenName
 * @property {number} statusesCount
 */
```

And use somewhere, something like:

```
/** @return {User} */
function getUser(){}
```